# Диалог и знаки при разрывах

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, диалог, многоточие

Друзья, мало того что заклинило, так еще не могу найти правило, наверное, потому, что даже вопрос затрудняюсь поставить. **Как правильно оформить диалог с разрывом**, где конец предложения от одного лица обрывается многоточием, а цитату (мысли, фразу предыдущего) продолжает второе лицо. Лучше на примере покажу.

**Пример:**

*- Помнишь, ты говорила мне, что встреть ты меня первым…*

*- Я бы никогда не вышла замуж за Макса! – перебила она его.*

Отсюда, собственно, **вопрос: верно ли будет написание в таком варианте или же необходимо многоточие перед вторым говорящим?**

**Как вариант:**

*- Помнишь, ты говорила мне, что встреть ты меня первым…*

*- ...Я бы никогда не вышла замуж за Макса! – перебила она его.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Многотичие в вашем примере не нужно, т.к здесь две самостоятельные реплики.

Вот правило, когда ставится многоточие.

Если одна реплика «разрывается» другой, а затем следует продолжение первой реплики, то после первой ее части и перед началом второй ставится многоточие:

— Я просил…

— Ничего вы не просили.

— …хотя бы минуту внимания.

Comment: А как быть не просто с обрывом(перебиванием, прерыванием) первого говорящего лица, а именно когда второе лицо продолжает предложение(мысль, фразу) первого лица? При этом первостепенная фраза когда-то ранее была сказана именно вторым лицом. То есть, по сути, первое лицо начинает цитировать фразу второго(когда-то и произнесенную им же – вторым лицом), а это второе лицо обрывает и договаривает свои же прошлые мысли. Хоть убей! Сколько прочитала ответов и правил , так и не вижу искомый вариант и уразуметь не могу каким образом соотнести это все с моим примером двух беседующих лиц. Помогите!

Comment: В подобных случаях надо ориентироваться на общие правила оформления диалогов. В приведенном вами примере и примере,который привел я, структура одна и та же.Если исходить только из значения фразы, правил не хватит. В правилах пунктуации приведенный вами случай отсутствует.

Comment: Многоточие в начале говорит о паузе в данном примере, поэтому если его поставить,получится,что собеседник долгое время молчал, а потом начал речь. Можете также оформить,как предложил shampar.

Answer (score 1):

Первое предложение вопросительное и должно заканчиваться знаком вопроса.

(Вы знаете, что такое сёстры милосердия?)

Относительно многоточия: фраза (*что встреть ты меня первым*), которая подхватывается далее по тексту, прямой речью не является и как прямая речь не оформлена. Следующая же, как и положено прямой речи, начинается с прописной, и в этом случае многоточие вначале предложения неуместно. Появление многоточия возможно только внутри предложения с закавыченной неполной цитатой.

(Л. Н. Толстой писал: «…в искусстве простота, краткость и ясность есть высшее совершенство формы искусства».)

Есть такой вариант, коль скоро желание видеть многоточие во второй фразе такое сильное:

— Помнишь, ты говорила мне, что встреть ты меня первым...

— Встреть я тебя первым... никогда не вышла бы за Макса? — перебила она его.

Comment: В качестве примера я указала именно диалог, а вопрос отнесла как к прямой речи, так и к ее виду - диалогу. Не пойму обоснование "неуместного" употребления многоточия. А как же быть с намеренной установкой паузы, допустим, в том же ответе лица на вопрос второго?

Comment: Кроме инструмента отточия есть и другие. Слово «неуместно» сказано для вас. Для ответа третьему лицу придётся залезть в правила употребления кавычек при прямой речи и цитате. Перед прописной в начале предложения может ставиться многоточие, если это продолжение прерванной фразы, но фраза была прервана другая и другим.

Comment: «....встреть ты меня первым… я бы никогда...» Здесь ТЫ и Я — один человек. Это не продолжение, а встреча разных фраз.

Comment: Мнение о встрече разных фраза я поняла. Но в остальном затрудняюсь понять вас. На всякий случай все же исправила вопрос, может, это я неверно его поставила.

Comment: Неверно и по термину изобретённому — диалог. с разрывом. Вариант решения с многоточием пришёл в голову. Допишу ответ.

Answer (score 1):

А пример с "Пиковой дамой" не подойдёт? Хотя и вижу, что типичное не то, предлагаю просто неожиданные решения, оставшиеся академическими ("частный случай игры в бисер").

> Особый случай пунктуационного оформления при «разрыве» заключенных в
>   кавычки слов (названий литературных произведений, различных
>   предприятий и т. д.) находим в таком примере: *«Пиковая…» ли это
>   «…дама»?* (реплика собеседника в ответ на утверждение, что
>   представленный текст является отрывком из «Пиковой дамы»).

Ещё близкое по проблематике:

> Прямая речь, принадлежащая разным лицам, выделяется кавычками
>   отдельно; при расположении в подбор, без указания на то, кому
>   принадлежат слова, реплики отделяются друг от друга тире: *«Самовар -
>   готов?» - «Нет еще...» - «Отчего? Там пришел кто-то». - «Авдотья
>   Гавриловна»* (М. Г.).
>
> ---

Думаю, что право на жизнь имеют оба варианта - и с отточием и без перед ответной репликой.

Это же авторское дело, а не учебникосоставителя.

Мне отточие нравится больше, чем его отсутствие; без него не ясно, что откликающийся подхватил и продолжил начатую не им фразу.